# cannot declare pointer to ‘const class FOO&’ error

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I can't understand why my compiler is giving me these errors:

```
brain.cpp:16: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘const class FACT&’
brain.cpp: In constructor ‘FACT::FACT(const FACT*)’:
brain.cpp:20: error: cannot convert ‘FACT**’ to ‘FACT*’ in assignment
brain.cpp: In member function ‘void FACT::AddRelation(FACT*)’:
brain.cpp:29: error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
brain.cpp:29: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘FACT*’ in initialization
brain.cpp:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘FACT’
brain.cpp:35: error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
brain.cpp:35: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘FACT*’ in assignment
brain.cpp:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘FACT’
brain.cpp: At global scope:
brain.cpp:47: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
brain.cpp:48: error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
brain.cpp:48: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘FACT*’ in initialization
brain.cpp:48: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘FACT’
brain.cpp: In function ‘void AddFact(FACT*)’:
brain.cpp:52: error: cannot convert ‘FACT**’ to ‘FACT*’ in initialization
brain.cpp:58: error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
brain.cpp:58: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘FACT*’ in assignment
brain.cpp:58: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘FACT’`
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class FACT
{
    public:
        FACT(string f)
        {
            fact=f;
            relations=NULL;
            num_relations=0;
        };
        ~FACT()
        {
            delete[] relations;
        };
        FACT(const FACT& *copy)
        {
            num_relations=copy->num_relations;
            delete[] relations;
            relations=new FACT*[num_relations];
            for (int x=0; x<=num_relations; x++)
            {
                relations[x]=copy->relations[x];
            }
            fact=copy->fact;
        };
        void AddRelation(FACT *fact)
        {
            FACT *copy=new *FACT[num_relations];
            for (int x=0; x<=num_relations; x++)
            {
                copy[x]=relations[x];
            }
            delete[] relations;
            relations=new *FACT[num_relations+1];
            for (int x=0; x<=num_relations; x++)
            {
                relations[x]=copy[x];
            }
            relations[num_relations+1]=fact;
            num_relations++;
        };
        string fact;
        FACT *relations;
        int num_relations;
};
FACT *facts=new *FACT[0];
int num_facts=0;
void AddFact(FACT *new_item)
{
    FACT *copy=new FACT*[num_facts];
    for (int x=0; x<=num_facts; x++)
    {
        copy[x]=facts[x];
    }
    delete[] facts;
    facts=new *FACT[num_facts+1];
    for (int x=0; x<=num_facts; x++)
    {
        facts[x]=copy[x];
    }
    delete[] copy;
    num_facts++;
    facts[num_facts]=new_item;
}
int main()
{
    FACT *new_item=new FACT("linux is secure");
    AddFact(new_item);
    delete[] facts;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.4.3 I can't understand why it doesn't consider "FACT" to be a data type

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare a pointer to a reference, like you try to do here:

```
FACT(const FACT& *copy)
```

There is no such thing as pointers to a reference. Probably you just wanted a reference, without a pointer:

```
FACT(const FACT& copy)
```

Comment: I thought that was how you did the copy constructor

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to declare a copy constructor. However it is not correct.

A copy constructor is declared as per the below quote from the Standard

> $12.8/2 - "A non-template constructor
>   for class X is a copy constructor if
>   its first parameter is of type X&,
>   const X&, volatile X& or const
>   volatile X&, and either there are no
>   other parameters or else all other
>   parameters have default arguments
>   (8.3.6)."

The parameter of the 'supposed to be copy constructor' has type 'pointer to reference'. This is disallowed by the Standard as per the quote below

> $8.3.2/5- "There shall be no
>   references to references, no arrays of
>   references, and no pointers to
>   references."

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first error is here:

```
FACT(const FACT& *copy)
```

Can't do that, you want a reference

```
FACT(const FACT& copy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, people. It is not all the truth.

Of course @noah can't declare

> a pointer to a reference

but the inverse, a reference to a pointer, is allowed.

```
FACT(const FACT *&copy)
```

is a valid syntax and very useful in some situations. Although, it is still a wrong copy constructor.

There are couples of good pages teaching this:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr390.htm
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/copyconstructors.html
http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/constructors.htm